# How can I set pseudo css for an elements after & before

Tags: css

I want to set a pseudo css for my elements.
I have css like this:

```
.element::before{
  font-size : 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

now, I want to change the css for lang, like:

```
.element::before:lang(en) { 
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

How can I do that? If any one please tell me about this.

Comment: So what is not working? Pseudo elements needs mandatory `content: ''` to work

Comment: Your approach seems ok, what is not working? Also can you share the html snippet as well?

Comment: Pseudo elements is working.
what I need is to set another Pseudo :lang(en) for :before

Comment: `.element:lang(en)::before`

Comment: @TemaniAfif  thank you, your code is working,
 thanks a lot